# Time series plot in R: Remove gaps from plot [zoo]

Tags: r, time-series, zoo

I have created a zoo object by extracting a time series from a RasterBrick:

```
library(zoo)
s <- RasterBrick

target_cell <- 23265

ss <- zooExtract(s, target_cell)

windows()
plot.zoo(ss, type = "o")
```

My result is shown below. I want a line to go through all the points, but I can't seem to make it work, I have looked through previous answers for this questions. I have tried `lines()` and it gives same result.

[image]

Comment: looks like you have NA values in your data, but cannot tell much without a reproducible example

Comment: Yes I have many data gaps and its an irregular time series, is this the problem?

Comment: These should work  `ss_filled  = zoo::na.locf(ss); plot.zoo(ss_filled, type = "o")` OR   `ss_complete_cases = ss[complete.cases(ss),];plot.zoo(ss_complete_cases , type = "o")` but also would recommend to save dates for missing data

Comment: Thank you Osssan, these worked perfectly! And the second option is exactly what I was looking for. If you add your comment as an answer I will mark my question as answered.

Comment: Try this: `plot(na.approx(ss)); points(ss)`

Comment: @G. Grothendieck, Thanks this works too, as well as plot(na.exclude(ss));  points(ss)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Richard Telford suggested the gaps in the plot are due to missing data.
    With base function `complete.cases` and `na.locf` from `zoo` the gaps
    could be removed or filled with previous observations as below:

```
#to identity periods with missing data

missingPeriod = as.Date(index(ss[!complete.cases(ss),]))


#to retain only periods with no missing data
ssComplete = ss[complete.cases(ss),]


#to retain all periods with gaps filled with previous value
#maxgap parameter controls number of missing data replaced with prev observation
N = 5
ssFilled = zoo::na.locf(ss,maxgap=N); 

#plots
plot.zoo(ssComplete , type = "o")

plot.zoo(ssFilled, type = "o")
```